# Cordova Background GeoLocation Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using this cordova plugin https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/ for an ios app, but running into some issues. Would appreciate if someone can help.

Here is the sample code I am using from the plugin example itself.

Issue is the callback function (callbackFn) doesn't seems to get called when a location change is detected, but I do get notifications on Iphone and I see one of the notification as Outstanding bg-task was force killed. Not sure what exactly this mean...

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
     bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
     if (window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation) {
        app.configureBackgroundGeoLocation();
      }
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    window.cache.clear( function(){console.log("cache cleared");}, function(){console.log("cache could not be cleared");} );
    require(['http://localhost:8080/sdm/app_resources/app_product_HY6I1FJ5KGRD/resources/js/main.js']);

},
configureBackgroundGeoLocation: function() {
        // Your app must execute AT LEAST ONE call for the current position via standard Cordova geolocation,
            //  in order to prompt the user for Location permission.
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
                 console.log('Location from Phonegap');
             });

            var bgGeo = window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation;

      /** This would be your own callback for Ajax-requests after POSTing background geolocation to your server.*/

            var yourAjaxCallback = function(response) {
                    bgGeo.finish();
                };

 /**This callback will be executed every time a geolocation is recorded in the background.*/
            var callbackFn = function(location) {
                console.log('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation callback:  ' + location.latitudue + ',' + location.longitude);
                // Do your HTTP request here to POST location to your server.
                 deviceId = 'I2FKRKXX8SQ0';
                 trackingToken = 'SomeSecurityToken';
                 jsonData={location:{longitude:location.longitude,latitude:location.latitude}};
                 var encodedToken = Base64.encode('tracker' + ':' + trackingToken);
                 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 var url = "http://localhost:8080/sdm/v1/KC/host/device/"+deviceId;

                 var params = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                 http.open("PUT", url, true);

                 //Send the proper header information along with the request
                 http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                 http.setRequestHeader("accept", "json");
                 http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedToken);
                 http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
                 http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

                /* http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                 if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                 alert(http.responseText);
                 }
                 }*/
                 http.send(params);

                yourAjaxCallback.call(this);
            };

            var failureFn = function(error) {
                    console.log('BackgroundGeoLocation error');
                }

            // BackgroundGeoLocation is highly configurable.
            bgGeo.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
                 desiredAccuracy: 10,
                 stationaryRadius: 20,
                 distanceFilter: 30,
                 activityType: 'AutomotiveNavigation',
                 debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
                 stopOnTerminate: false
               });

            // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.  The user will be tracked whenever they suspend the app.
            bgGeo.start();

            // If you wish to turn OFF background-tracking, call the #stop method.
            // bgGeo.stop()
        }
```

};

Answer (score 4):

You can try my background plugin if you wish, it uses pure javascript callbacks for ios AND android.

https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-background-geolocation-services

Comment: Hi, looks great! I have one question though, have you successfully submitted an app to Apple App Store? I hear they don't allow Cordova BG services!

Comment: I have two applications in production that use my background plugin. Its just using their own libraries underneath so there shouldn't be anything to bar you from submitting the app.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the plugin and the response :)

Comment: Your library is great!

Comment: can we track location even if the app is closed ?

Comment: @Anant tracking will not continue if the application is force closed by the user.

Comment: @user1221612 that's not true . I have cordova app live with this permission. The process to hybrid or native are very rigorous , a person will call you to get explanation why you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using android. Unless you have premium version of Christrocracy plugin, it will not execute your callback function. You will have to specify `url` for the location to be sent for android devices.

[Christocracy Background Geooction Plugin](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add callback function and failure function in the start as well. I had the same problem.
E.g. The configuration: `bgGeo.configure(callbackFn, failureFn...
bgGeo.start();` must be changed to `bgGeo.start(callbackFn, failureFn);`